# Show $R \setminus S$ is a union of prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-verification

I'm stuck on the following question:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, and $S \subseteq R$ a saturated multiplicative set (that is, $1 \in S$ and $x, y \in S$ if and only if $xy \in S$).  Show that $R \setminus S$ is a union of prime ideals.

Here's my attempt so far.  If $a \in R \setminus S$, then the ideal $Ra$ does not intersect $S$, because if $ra$ were in $S$ for some $r \in R$, then $a$ would have to be in $S$.  Thus, it follows by Zorn's lemma that there exist ideals $I$ of $R$ *which are maximal with respect to the property that $I \cap S = \emptyset$*.

Let $I$ be any such ideal.  If I can show that $I$ is prime, the conclusion will follow.  Let $xy \in I$.  I want to show that $x$ or $y$ is in $I$.  Suppose $x \not\in I$.  Then $I + Rx$ intersects $S$, so there exists $s \in S, a \in I, r \in R$ such that $s = a + rx$.  Then $sy = ay + rxy \in I$, so $sy$, and hence $y$, cannot be in $S$.

Similarly if $y$ is not in $I$, then $x \not\in S$.  So we are reduced to proving the following is impossible: $xy \in I$, $x$ and $y$ are not in $S$, but they aren't in $I$ either.

Comment: Two remarks. (1) Actually one has: for any subset $S\subset R$, it holds $S$ is a saturated multiplicatively closed subset iff $R-S$ is a union of prime ideals.

Comment: $\def\S{\overline{S}}\def\p{\mathfrak{p}}$(2) The result (1) has an easy corollary: if $S\subset R$ is any multiplicatively closed subset, define $$\S=\{x\in R\mid\exists y\in R:xy\in S\}.$$ It's an exercise to show that $\S$ is the smallest saturated multiplicatively closed subset of $R$ containing $S$ ($\S$ is called the *saturation* of $S$). The corollary is: $R-\S$ is the union of the primes of $R$ disjoint from $S$. By (1), it suffices to show that every prime $\p\subset R$ disjoint from $S$ is also disjoint from $\S$. But if $x\in\p\cap\S$, then there is $y\in R$ with $xy\in\p\cap S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show that if such $x,y$ exist, then $I$ is not maximal w.r.t. $I\cap S=\emptyset.$

Incidentally, you should adjust your maximality condition slightly to say that *for each* $a\in R\setminus S,$ there is an ideal $I$ with $a\in I$ such that $I$ is maximal w.r.t. $I\cap S=\emptyset.$ (Do you see why this adjustment is necessary?)

Comment: how can we prove $I$ is not maximal?

Comment: Well, what would it mean for an ideal $I$ to be maximal with respect to the condition $I\cap S=\emptyset$?

Answer (score 4):

You need to show that if $x,y \notin I$, then $xy \notin I$.  Consider the product $(I  + (x))(I + (y)) \subseteq I + (xy)$.

Edit:  Further details...  (Spoiler alert.)  See the original question for what $I$ is and why we need to show that $I$ is prime.  Suppose to the contrary that $xy \in I$ for some $x,y \notin I$.  Then $(I + (x))(I + (y)) = I^2 + xI + yI + (xy) \subseteq I$.  Since $I + (x)$ and $I + (y)$ properly contain $I$, they must each contain an element of $S$, and hence their product contains an element of $S$.  (Here we use the fact that $S$ is multiplicatively closed.)  Thus $I$ contains an element of $S$, a contradiction.

Comment: Can you explain more, please? The converse is still right. Could you help me prove it?

Comment: I see. Thank you so much