# S is saturated if and only if R\S, the complement of S in R, is the union of some (possibly empty) family of prime ideals of R

Tags: commutative-algebra

I got problem which is the same here but I can not solve follow the way 2 of them pointing out
[Show $R \setminus S$ is a union of prime ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418829/show-r-setminus-s-is-a-union-of-prime-ideals)
Please help me explain more.
And one more thing I wanna ask that the converse is still right. Could you give the solution of the converse?

Comment: Do you mean you _cannot_ follow the two answers, and want a more detailed working-out?

Comment: I mean I got the stuck which is exactly the same in the last sentence of this post. I see the hints but I still can not prove it.

Comment: Then when you say, in your question, that "I can solve", that was a typo? I'll write something down, just give me a few minutes.

Comment: I see@@. That was my mistake. Thank you